# Use environmental variable in pip requirements file

Tags: heroku, pip

I've added the following to my requirements.txt file to be used in a Heroku app:

```
git+https://username:my_real_password@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

However, I don't want the password in my repo, so I want to create an enviromental variable in Heroku called PASSWORD and set it equal to 'my_real_password'.

I then change the line in the requirements file to:

```
git+https://username:$PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
```

but pip interpret my password as $PASSWORD.

So my question is, how can I force pip to lookup an environmental variable? Is there some escape character I can use?

Comment: any reason you do not want to use git+ssh and authenticate with an ssh-key?

Comment: That is want I wanted to do originally, but I could not figure out how to create ssh keys on heroku. The 'heroku keys' command is for adding my public key to heroku. If I understand it correctly, what I need to do is create a private and public key in heroku that it will use to get the package from bitbucket. Do you know how to set that up?